# C# Return numeric values if the user enters characters

Tags: c#

I am new to C# and was playing with the loops, I just want to know how I can set the variable **userTarget** equal to an integer value in case if the user enters strings, i tried the TryParse method but I don't know if I really understand what I am doing with that.

```
static void Main()
{
    string userChoice = string.Empty;

    do
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter your target?");
        int userTarget = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        int start = 0;

        while (start <= userTarget)
        {
            Console.Write(start + " ");
            start += 2;
        }

        do
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Do you want to continue?");
            userChoice = Console.ReadLine().ToUpper();

            if (userChoice != "YES" && userChoice != "NO")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Invalid choice, please say yes or no");
            }

        } while (userChoice != "YES" && userChoice != "NO");

    } while (userChoice == "YES");

}
```

Comment: It would be easier to have just one loop, inside which you ask user for an input and then route (process input): do A, do B, exit, etc. Look into *state machine* too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`TryParse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse?view=netcore-3.1) is definitely the way to go for user input

> Converts the string representation of a number to its 32-bit signed
>   integer equivalent. A return value indicates whether the operation
>   succeeded.

Example of continual validation

```
int userChoice = -1;

...

Console.WriteLine("Please enter your target?");
while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out userTarget))
    Console.WriteLine("You had one job, enter a target...");

Console.WriteLine($"You entered : {userChoice}");
```

Comment: Small note with this answer: my users would definitely not appreciate the rude response when they do something wrong ! what about a relevant error message and a repeat of the question, like **Console.WriteLine("Error: invalid input, expect numeric value.\nPlease enter your target ? ");**

Comment: @Goodies plus one for being nice to your users, and the more descriptive message